# How to estimate the number of nodes between the current node and some other node in Kademlia?

Tags: metrics, dht, kademlia

In Kademlia, all (key, value) pairs stored by the node, aside from the ones that were originally published by the current node itself, have an expiration time based on where the current node is located in relation to the key. If the current node is of the k-closest nodes to the key, the (key, value) pair expires when it outlives the 24h from when it was originally published. If it's not a k-closest node, the expiration time is

> inversely proportional to the number of nodes between the current node and the node whose ID is closest to the key ID

as per Kademlia paper. The paper also says that

> this number can be inferred from the bucket structure of the current node.

There seem to be two very different ways to count nodes between the current node and the given node, and I'm not sure which one is right. We assume flat array routing table implementation next, an array with 160 buckets pre-allocated.

1. [Xlattice Kademlia Design Specification page](http://xlattice.sourceforge.net/components/protocol/kademlia/specs.html#expiration) says that you should find a bucket index j into which the given node would fall into and count the nodes in buckets 0..j, counting all nodes in 0..j-1 and counting only nodes that are closer to the current node than the key in the final bucket j.
2. ["Implementation of the Kademlia Distributed Hash Table" semester thesis by Bruno Spori](https://pub.tik.ee.ethz.ch/students/2006-So/SA-2006-19.pdf) (section "Calculation of the Number of Intermediate Nodes") calculates the distance between the current node and the given node, and counts nodes only in the buckets that have the distance less or equal to the distance between the current node and the given node.

Both those methods seem right to me, but they are completely different and yield different results. The first method counts nodes between the current node and the given node based on the distance between the current node and other nodes in our buckets. The second method counts nodes between the current node and the given node based on the distance between the given node and other nodes in our buckets.

For example, if the current node has ID `0001_0100` (let's assume 8-bit ids for the sake of the example), there are only 8 buckets that contain nodes with the following prefixes:
`0001_0101`, `0001_011x`, `0001_00xx`, `0001_1xxx`, `0000_xxxx`, `001x_xxxx`, `01xx_xxxx`, `1xxx_xxxx`.
Let's say we want to calculate expiration time for a key `1010_0010`.
The distance between the current node and the given node is 182 (`0001_0100 xor 1010_0010 = 182`).

Using the first method, we would count all nodes in buckets 0..6 plus the nodes in the bucket 7 that are closer to the current node than the given ID.
This works because the distances between the current node and all the buckets are: 1, 2, 4, 12, 20, 52, 84, 148.
You can find them by xoring our ID with the range the bucket covers (I replaced x with 0 to get the smallest, but not necessarily the closest, ID that would fall into that bucket), e.g. `0001_0100 xor 0001_0101 = 1` and `0001_0100 xor 1000_0000 = 148`.
All nodes up to the last one would have nodes that are <= 182 (the distance between the current node and the given ID) away from the current node. The last bucket can have nodes that are further away.
So we count the number of nodes in all 8 buckets (with partially counting the last one).

Using the second method, we count all nodes in buckets 1, 2, 4, 5 and 7. We do not count buckets 0, 3, 6.
This works because the distances between the given ID and the buckets are: 183, 180, 178, 186, 162, 130, 226, 34.
You can find them by xoring the given ID with the range the bucket covers (I replaced x with 0 to get the smallest, but not necessarily the closest, ID that would fall into that bucket), e.g. `1010_0010 xor 0001_0101 = 183` and `1010_0010 xor 1000_0000 = 34`.
Only buckets 1, 2, 4, 5 and 7 have nodes with a distance less than 182 (the distance between the current node and the given ID) with respect to the given ID.
So we count nodes only in 5 buckets out of 8.

Counting nodes in 8/8 buckets and 5/8 buckets is a big difference. Which method is the right one? Both seem to count the number of nodes between the current node and the given key, but the result is so different.

Note that the xor metric holds here, there doesn't seem to be any mistake made here. For example, the distance between the current node and a node residing the last bucket is `0001_0100 xor 1000_0000 = 148`. The distance between the given node and the same node in the last bucket is `1010_0010 xor 1000_0000 = 34`. `148 xor 34 = 182`, so `d(a, b) = d(a, c) xor d(c, b)` holds.

The first method seems to count all nodes the current node knows of that are closer than 182 from the current node. The second method seems to count all nodes the current node knows of that are closer than 182 from the given node.

I'm thinking that the second method is more correct, as we want to find if we are a k-closest node to the given key. When finding nodes close to a given ID, i.e. the `FIND_NODE` RPC, you do so using a process similar to the second method to identify which buckets contain nodes closest to the given ID, e.g. in the given example those would be buckets 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, 3, 6 - in that exact order, with the closest first.

But then again, the first method also makes sense as we know the best about our own surrounding. We know the whole 8 buckets of nodes closer than 182 to the current node, while we know only about 5 buckets of nodes closer than 182 to the given key.

Comment: Note that 2. just counts the nodes and 1. has `exp(k /C)` in its calculation.

Comment: Note that (2) does the inverse exponent too, it's just that the section I pointed to is titled "Calculation of the Number of Intermediate Nodes", which deals just with calculating the number of intermediate nodes and nothing else.That number is then used in the inverse exponent, as per "2.6 Republishing and Other Recurring Tasks": "The lifetime of a stored <key,value>-pair is exponentially inversely proportional to the number of nodes between the own id and the node whose id is closest to the respective key."

Answer (score 0):

I lack intuition for the flat routing table layout, having long switched to the [tree-based layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161732/1362755) in my own implementation. So I will argue based on the latter instead.

The simplest approach for decaying the storage time in the tree-based layout to see into which bucket a storage key would fall. If it falls into the deepest bucket (depth *d*) it gets the full time (*T*). For *d-1* it gets *T/2*, for *d-2* it gets *T/4* and so on.

This is can be inaccurate if [non-local splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129978/highly-unbalanced-kademlia-routing-table/32187456#32187456) is implemented, in which case one should consider the shallowest bucket of the k-closest set as the maximum depth.

An alternative approach, that should also work with the flat layout, is that one first estimates the global node density in the keyspace and then uses the rule of three to get the node count for any distance. The estimates can be obtained various ways. Using the distances in the k-closest set from the routing table for the local node ID is the simplest but also noisiest one (which should be equivalent to the correction for non-local splitting above).

To check the algorithms I would use numerical simulation since even millions of IDs and distances can be calculated in a few seconds. Construct populations of N nodes (for varying N), represented by their IDs, then build a bunch of perfect routing tables for random node IDs within each population and then run your estimator for a bunch of intervals and calculate the error relative to the actual count from the simulated population.

Comment: So, back to my original question, which of the two methods I have mentioned you think is more accurate?

Comment: Simulating them both and seeing for myself is a good suggestion, but that requires implementing a good chunk of Kademlia, which is too much work, which is why I have asked this question. I'm trying to reason about it theoretically on paper, and I can't find very strong points for one against the other.

Comment: You don't actually have to implement much of kademlia for these simulations. You need N-bit XOR (bignums) and a crude routing table (array of structs or an ordered map plus some insert/lookup logic).