# Bucket splitting exception in Kademlia

Tags: p2p, distributed-system, dht, kademlia

In the section "Routing" in the original paper, the problem of the normal bucket splitting rule is described as follows:

> Every node with prefix 001 would have an empty k-bucket into which u should be inserted, yet u's bucket refresh would only notify [$ k]of the node.

I don't understand why it is a problem. Why does every node with prefix 001 needs to receive u's bucket refresh?

I have read the original paper and have spent quite amount of time researching the bucket splitting, but I couldn't figure out. Can any one explain?

Thank you

Comment: I can't Ctrl+F through the paper, can you mention which section and paragraph that quote comes from?

Comment: It's at the first line after the diagram on page 8.

Answer (score 0):

That's the [highly unbalanced tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32129978/1362755) case. For kademlia to work properly it must have nearly-exact view of its neighborhood while only needing a subsampled views of more remote portions of the keyspace.

The initially described bucket splitting algorithm would only split a bucket when its ID-range covers the node's own ID. But if a node's nearest neighbors don't fall into this bucket then maintaining an exhaustive view of the neighborhood requires a non-covering bucket to be split (or in [S/Kademlia](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.4986&rep=rep1&type=pdf): an explicit neighborhood list to be maintained).